# Jquery Cross-Browser Scroll Event Issues

Tags: jquery, scroll, cross-browser

I have a jquery function that animates items when the user scrolls past them.

One of my items "stops" the user and prevents natural scrolling from occuring.

Instead, it turns the natural scrolling into the progress bar of the item, downward scrolling bring the item to 100% completion, and then natural scrolling resumes.

Currently it seems to work perfectly on Firefox, however on IE and Chrome I'm experiencing a jittering effect. It seems to occur less when using the keyboard arrow keys, and more with the scroll wheel or bar. I have some theories, but everything I've tested seems to lead me to believe the solution I have is correct.

Here's a link to the dev environment, the item occurs after only a bit of scrolling, and it's quite apparent which one it is. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[Dev Environment](http://dev.thinkswift.com/)

Comment: If that can help you (or not) the same jittering appears in Safari on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how about in Firefox on Mac?

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox, same jittering appears in Chrome, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a perfect solution, the code was re-written to be handled by more specific, individual elements.

For example, instead of using the .scroll method to handle the issue (which was causing a recursive loop by scrolling during the .scroll), I handled the interaction through the different scroll methods (arrow keys, scroll wheel, scroll bar) and was able to separate the behavior.

Hopefully this helps someone else who stumbles along this.